# Are applications developed using 3rd party mobile application development tools acceptable to their respective markets?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, mobile-phones

I am trying to implement application that is supported to android,iphone,blackberry,windows mobile,symbian, webos (palm).

For that I am using the 3rd party applications [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development)

However, upon research I found that Android market doesn't accept the application that is developed on total cross tool.

Same for iphone to use application that is done on total cross mobile must be jail broken.

So, now I am in confusion that, is mobile applications those are developed using 3rd party Mobile application development tools are acceptable with their respected marckets.

For example, if I develop an application using phonegap tool on android, will android market accept that application?

Comment: Bedrock is not available, TotalCross cannot be used for development for those peripherals and PhoneGap is for web applications. What's the sense of this question?

Comment: can u please see this link u found tools.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development

Comment: @marzapower: Bedrock is not available? http://www.metismo.com/platforms-mobilenative.html

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at another project, with the same name, that barely fitted with this problem.

Comment: As far as i am aware of,Apple has confirmed that the framework has its approval, even with the new 4.0 developer license agreement changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS and Android application stores have plenty of applications built using cross-platform frameworks. Apple originally suggested they would restrict these platforms, but they backed off from this position last year as shown here:

http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/09statement.html

I have to disagree with Sheikh Aman, however. I believe there are several platforms that do that. According to the original poster's link, [Bedrock](http://www.metismo.com) does so.

It's a little misleading to say that [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) is for mobile websites--it's true it uses JavaScript+CSS, but their apps are packaged so they can be sold through the app store.

My company's product, the [Particle SDK](http://www.particlecode.com), covers Android, BlackBerry, iPhone, webOS, and WinPhone7, and legacy support is available for Symbian, but so far we haven't had much call for it. Particle apps are written in Java or ActionScript, not JavaScript.

If the original poster actually needs Windows Mobile, as opposed to Windows Phone 7, Bedrock or PhoneGap might fit the bill.

I haven't tested those toolkits, but they both have applications in the app store. EA's iPhone Battleship game is apparently a Bedrock app.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Appcelarator is very well accepted in app-store and in Android market too.

Phone Gap is for mobile websites.

Most importantly, there's no cross-platform development environment available, which lets you develop for Android+iPhone+WP7+BB+Symbian by writing a JS (or whatever) only once.

Comment: @Lord But i did n't found any link's to donwload bedrock.

Comment: i guess it actually costs money :)